# Как редактировать вид записей в Elementor Pro?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Как редактировать вид записей в Elementor Pro? На главной странице у меня отображаются записи. С помощью Элементора я отредактировал их внешний вид на главной, но у меня появился новый вопрос. Когда я нажимаю на запись на главной странице, она открывается полностью на новой страничке. Как редактировать эту страницу которая открывается? Редактировать именно через Элементор. Если что у меня PRO версия. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Templates -> Theme Builder -> Single (либо Single Post в новом Theme Builder)

Дальше выбираете тип записи необходимой Вам, даете название темплейту и создаете новый темплейт. Подробнее можете посмотреть [здесь](https://elementor.com/help/creating-a-single-post-template-with-elementor-pro/).